# In Kubernetes How to patch a container within a deployment

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I would like to add a volume to a container using the patch API (not apply)

This patch isn't working:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: cep-debug-dir
          persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: cep-pvc-debug
      containers:
        name: cep
        - mountPath: /debug
          name: cep-debug-dir
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /debug
            name: cep-debug-dir
```

My use case is to extend the deployment yaml adding a mounted volume for development and in general have a polymorphic deployment without repeating yaml code and having to maintain changes in two files.

p.s
I'm using config map and if I could use an if to mount the volume conditionally it would bee cool.

Answer (score 1):

I printed the deployment json and used / edited the fields in json format and the patch worked
In terminal

```
kubectl patch deploy cep --patch "$(cat cep-deploy-patch.yaml)"
```

file:

```
{
    "spec": {
        "template": {
            "spec": {
                "containers": [{
                    "name": "cep",
                    "volumeMounts": [{
                        "mountPath": "/debug",
                        "name": "cep-debug-dir"
                    }]
                }],
                "volumes": [{
                    "name": "cep-debug-dir",
                    "persistentVolumeClaim": {
                        "claimName": "cep-pvc-debug"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```