# OpenShift Patching for adding PVC to a DeploymentConfig

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, openshift, kubernetes-pvc

Hello I'm currently trying to add something to my DC so that it can look like below (Note: `volumeMounts` and `volume` elements does not exist yet -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        ...
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: postgres-pv-claim
      volumes:
      - name: postgres-pv-claim
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

Note that the `postgres-pv-claim` elements don't exist and I'm trying to add them via patch.
I've tried using something like the following to patch it to no avail -

```
oc patch dc/postgres --type=json --patch '
[
  { 
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/volumeMounts",
    "value": [
        {
            "name": "postgres-pv-claim",
            "- mountPath": "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
        }
     ]
  }
]
```

The error looks as follows -

```
The DeploymentConfig "postgres" is invalid: 
* spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "postgres-pv-claim"
* spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].mountPath: Required value
```

Is my path wrong?

Comment: Does this ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017828/in-kubernetes-how-to-patch-a-container-within-a-deployment ) answer your question? Also, the `- mountPath` does not look ok to me, probably needs to be `mountPath`. As for the name not found, is the volume defined under `spec.template.spec.volumes` ? If not, you need to add it as well in the patch

Comment: I'm a little confused; your original `Deployment` already appears to contain a `volumeMount` element with a `mountPath` and `name` identical to what you're trying to add.